# Receive index error pop from empty list in Python

Tags: python, postfix-notation

I received an Index error: pop from empty list when using my test file running multiple lines of arithmetic expressions. Postfix notation applied. Current version of Python I am using is 2.7.6. The error I receive is Index error: pop from empty list . and it points to this line return self.items.pop(). When only using 1 line of text within the text file, the output is correct. However, whenever I place multiple lines of arithmetic expressions in my test file, I receive this error which does not seem to make any sense.
Here is some sample input included in my text file .                 4.3 5 7.5 * + 4 5 + * 
3 4 / 2.3 * - 3 -  the command i used was cat test.txt | python something.py

The command I am running is cat test.txt | python something.py.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import fileinput

class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.items == []

    def push(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        return self.items.pop()

    def peek(self):
        return self.items[len(self.items)-1]

    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)
```

Comment: Please provide an executable piece of code to reproduce the error. Use StringIO or post a short version of your input file.

Comment: @barrios Here is some sample input included in my text file .                 4.3 5 7.5 * + 4 5 + * 
3 4 / 2.3 * - 3 -  the command i used was cat test.txt | python something.py

Comment: The code you've posted will only print the result of a single expression, and it works fine on my machine with the data you've given, even if that expression is split over multiple lines. If you have multiple expressions, or you don't have enough operators to reduce the stack to a single item then `-E` is printed. You'll get the `IndexError: pop from empty list` if you have too many operators for the amount of numbers currently on the stack.

Comment: BTW you have a minor typo: the last `elif` statement should be `elif line == "**":`. FWIW, there's a more compact way to do this that doesn't require a giant `if...elif` suite: you can use a dictionary of [operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html?module-operator) functions indexed by the operator string.

Comment: Why did you just edit out most of your code?

Comment: Can't reproduce (at least with the current version).